# How to call MCollective from java client

Tags: java, cluster-computing, puppet, java-client, mcollective

I have setup a cluster using puppet. Now I need to call call puppet agents for puppet master. For that I am planing to use MCollective. I have another requirement, need to call MCollective from a java client in order to achieve change client configurations from master and restart the servers. Is there a way to do it?.
Thanks,
Irham

Comment: See this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mcollective-users/yzJcOZa0v3Y

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using jruby. I installed the ruby gems mcollective-client,json and jruby-openssl using rvm. In the following example I am calling a simple mco puppet runonce

Java code

```
ScriptingContainer ruby = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
Object result = ruby.runScriptlet(PathType.ABSOLUTE,"/opt/ruby_test.rb");
```

Ruby code

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'mcollective'
 include MCollective::RPC
 mc = rpcclient("puppet")
 printrpc mc.runonce()
 mc.disconnect
```